# Vue 3 component rendering not working on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-apps-script, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm starting with Vue and Vue 3 coding an app on Google Apps Script.

I'm following Vue Mastery tutorials and also I've found this amazing example by @brucemcpherson of a Vue 2 app working on GAS, but too difficult for me to understand some parts.

https://ramblings.mcpher.com/vuejs-apps-script-add-ons/

GitHub: https://github.com/brucemcpherson/bmVuetemplate

Somehow there's something tricky with GAS and Vue working with components and I need some help.

This are my files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
      </my-component></my-component>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-beta.12/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <?!= include("main-js"); ?>
    <?!= include("my-component"); ?>
    <script>
      const mountedApp = app.mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**utils.gs**

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

**main-js.html**

```
<script>
  const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
          return {
              product: 'Socks'
          }
      }
  })
</script>
```

**my-component.html**

```
<script>
  app.component('my-component', {
    template: `<div>My component content</div>`,
    data() {
          return {
              product: 'Boots'
          }
      }
  })
</script>
```

I get the warning on console:

```
dropping postMessage.. was from host https://script.google.com but expected host https://n-jogxx7ovu3afq6djr4pskwjsglfwozzlkf5baay-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com
```

Both cases, nothing happen: I can't see my component when index.html charged.

Do you have any idea of what could be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first initiate the vue, then mount the app. Not sure if this was your issue, but here's a working codepen. Also, I 've imported the vue lib in 
https://codepen.io/tzknc/pen/PopbOWW

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
  <my-component/>
</div>

<script>
  // create the vue instance 
  const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        product: 'Socks',
      }
    }
  });
  // add the component 
  app.component('my-component', {
    template: `
    <div>
      My component content | {{product}}
    </div>`,
    data() {
          return {
              product: 'Boots'
          }
      }
  })
  // mount it 
  const mountedApp = app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your soon response, @tzknc. I'm not sure what was the problem, but your code works like a charm on Google Apps Script.

My real case includes importing Vuetify, but some how I cannot include Vuetify css with success using Vue on GAS.

Because it seams that include the <link> on <head> tags it's not working for me...

But maybe this should be a second question.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm just reading that Vuetify 2x is not compatible with Vue 3...